# Filter out element one by one using filter()

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I will kick start with my question:

I have an array:

`int[] arr = { 1,2,3,4,5 };` , i want to store values to a `List<Integer> li` like this : `14,13,12,11,10`

How these values came to the List `li` like this??

Our initial numbers are **1,2 ,3 ,4** , and **5** . We can calculate the following sums using four of the five integers:

- If we sum everything except 1, our sum is 14.
- If we sum everything except 2, our sum is 13.
- If we sum everything except 3, our sum is 12.
- If we sum everything except 4, our sum is 11.
- If we sum everything except 5, our sum is 10.

My approach and thoughts:

I thought i already have an `int [] arr` , so i will make it to stream , now i will `filter` out each elements one by one and will `sum` rest in each iteration and will add this to List `li`.

```
List<Integer> li   = IntStream.range(0,1).filter(i-> arr[i] !=i).sum();
```

^^ This did not worked, I am thinking can i do some this like below?

```
IntStream.range(0,1).filter(i-> filter(this is anotherfilter)).sum();
```

I am not able to understand this, i want to do this problem with streams and java-8.

Comment: could the initial array have duplicate elements? what would be your output for `int[] arr = { 1,2,3,4,5 ,6,4,2};` and think what your current logic would do to this input.

Comment: @Naman , no duplicate elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can break it into two steps and perform the operation as:

```
int[] arr = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
int total = Arrays.stream(arr).sum(); // total of the array
List<Integer> output = Arrays.stream(arr)
        .mapToObj(integer -> total - integer) // (total - current) value as element
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: wht to do mapToObj ?? I find it complex , i often see map , maptoint..etc. Any relevant article to learn this concept?

Comment: When i give input `7 ,69, 2 ,221, 8974` the first and last list numbers are **299 9266** but they should be **299 9271**

Comment: @JokaLee since its an `IntStream`, you can alternately use `boxed()` to convert to `Stream<Integer>` and then simply use `map`

Comment: @JokaLee you start with an array of `int`, but want a `List` of `Integer`. So you need either, `boxed()` or `mapToObj(…)`, to get from `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>`.

Comment: @JokaLee why should it be *`9271`* the sum of `69, 2 ,221, 8974` would be `9266`, isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: @JokaLee your notion of “first” and “last” seems to be wrong. That’s not the same as “smallest” and “largest”, unless you sort you array.

Comment: yeah, i get it now Holger, i was looking for min and max. Thank you you seems visionary +1

Answer (score 1):

```
IntStream.range(0, arr.length)
             .map(x -> IntStream.of(arr).sum() - arr[x])
             .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Or `IntStream.of(arr).sum()` can be computed only once as a single variable.

Comment: Is there any SO post which examples nested filter() with example?

Comment: @JokaLee sorry I don't get it. what is your question?

Comment: I want to learn how can we write filter inside filter in complex scenario, is there any stackoverflow answer available with example? Thank you sir for all answers here.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Supplier<IntStream> supplier = () -> IntStream.range(1, 6);
    supplier.get()
             .map(integer -> supplier.get().sum() - integer)
             .forEach(item -> System.out.println(item));
```

Instead of **forEach**, you can use **collect(Collectors.toList())** to collect integers to the list